# Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE800000E). How can I solve this?

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode7.3

I am trying to run my iOS app in my iPad. When running the app an error message is showing in Xcode:

> An error was encountered while enabling development on this device.
>   Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE800000E)

I have tried rebooting my device twice and reset the device but the same error is showing.

I have Xcode 7.3.1, osx el-capitan in my Mac 10.11.4 and os in my iPad 9.3.2.

Please help me  to solve this error.